# Is there a word/idiom for feigning a belief for the purpose of constructing an argument?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Currently I'm using the phrase "Operating on the premise that". Here's an example:

> Operating on the premise that the God depicted in the Old Testament is real, I would provide a sacrificial lamb.

I want to be able to talk about this practice in the abstract.

> When I am [new abstraction]ing, I'm able to empathize better and learn from my new frame of mind.

I could establish an acronym (OOPT) and refer to the practice as OOPTing but I feel like logicians or writers must have already solved this, as it's a fundamental behaviour in a lot of practices.

Comment: I feel like it's a specific subset of speculation, maybe? Speculation would certainly include behaviours that do not apply, like predicting the outcome of an election.

Comment: I'd call it "devil's advocate".

Comment: assume, stipulate, concede, presume

Comment: This has been great, a lot of good answers. Thank you folks!

Comment: @brian_o - You forgot "*postulate*" that also also matches.

Comment: Positing! I forgot about positing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me additionally suggest the term "**arguendo**": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arguendo.

You can also simply start your sentence with **"Assuming..."**.

Google Ngram for "arguendo":

[image]

Comment: I am going to let this sit for a while but odds are good I will accept this answer, as 'arguendoing', while ungrammatical, suits my purposes. Probably I could go figure out the correct conjugation, too.

Answer (score 12):

"**For argument's sake**" is, in my experience, a common idiom and, in fact, has been used as the title of at least one [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142086954X).

A slight variation is "**For the sake of argument**" which was addressed in [xkcd #1432](http://www.xkcd.com/1432/) (see an [explanation here](http://explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1432:_The_Sake_of_Argument)). The title text on the image states in part:

> ...it's a DEVICE for EXPLORING a PLAUSIBLE REALITY that's not the one we're in, to gain a broader understanding about it.

Additionaly, the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/for-the-sake-of-argument) offers the following definition for the later (but does not list the former):

> As a basis for discussion or reasoning.

According to Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+argument%27s+sake%2Cfor+the+sake+of+argument&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfor%20argument%20%27s%20sake%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20argument%20%27s%20sake%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFor%20argument%20%27s%20sake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cfor%20the%20sake%20of%20argument%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20the%20sake%20of%20argument%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BFor%20the%20sake%20of%20argument%3B%2Cc0), the latter seems to be more common.

[image]

The aforementioned comic also makes mention of "**playing devil's advocate**".

Answer (score 1):

I commonly hear it put as **playing the devil's advocate**.

> In common parlance, a devil's advocate is someone who, given a certain argument, takes a position they do not necessarily agree with (or simply an alternative position from the accepted norm), for the sake of debate or to explore the thought further.

[Devils Advocate Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate)

Google Ngrams seem to also be popular, so here's one.

[image: comparison of arguendo, for argument's sake, and devil's advocate]

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***premising***.

> **PREMISE**
>
> : (used with object) to assume, either explicitly or implicitly, (a
>   proposition) as a premise for a conclusion.
>
> : (used without object) to state or assume a premise. [Random
>   House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/premise?s=t)

Answer (score 1):

> **Supposing** that the God depicted in the Old Testament is real, I would provide a sacrificial lamb.

I think this fits quite well in sentences where the assumption of a premise is being made. However, I don't think it works very well for talking about assuming a premise:

> When I am **supposing**, I'm able to empathize better and learn from my new frame of mind.

Perhaps that can be worked around through a rephrasing:

> **Suppositions** allow me to empathize better and learn from my new frame of mind.

[image: ngram- supposing, for the sake of argument]

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it for the purposes of setting it up to completely knock down later, it's called a "Straw Man" argument.

A "Devil's Advocate" is probably the most correct, but in common usage sometimes people go with the completely informal "Let's just say...."

Answer (score 0):

Certain interpretations of "Rhetoric" seem to fit your requirements. Certainly politicians will feign belief for the purpose of constructing an argument favorable to them.